# Email Notification Templates {entry_url}

Tags: templates, email, notification

I've set up an automatic response when a new entry is posted, I've included the template below. It's working fine, but the {entry_url} is wrong, it's sending an older URL from the dev version of the site.  Does anyone know where I can change this?

A new entry has been posted in the following channel:
{channel_name}

The title of the entry is:
{entry_title}

Posted by: {name}
Email: {email}

To read the entry please visit:
{entry_url}

Comment: Already tried a Tool -> Data -> Clear Cache?
Do you have any configuration bootstrap file/folder?

Comment: Hi Miksamsa, that's for help.  I've cleared the caches, but I've found it in the meantime, it's in Admin > Channel Administration > Channels > Edit Preferences > Channel URL .  Thanks again